# Why the validation data is small?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, data-science, image-classification

When I break by image dataset into train and validation using the following code:

```
datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.20)
valid_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(**datagen_kwargs)
valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  TRAINING_DATA_DIR,
  subset="validation",
  shuffle=True,
  target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE
)
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(**datagen_kwargs)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  TRAINING_DATA_DIR,
  subset="training",
  shuffle=True,
  target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE)
```

I get the following output: "Found 1997 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 7999 images belonging to 5 classes."

So my validation data has 1997 images and train data has 7999 images.

Now, I am trying to make predictions on the validation data using my trained model. I use `val_image_batch, val_label_batch = next(iter(valid_generator))` to extract the images and labels. When I print the length of `val_image_batch` or `val_label_batch` I get 32 instead of 1997- the size of my validation data.

I want to make predictions on the entire validation data and not just 32 images. Can someone help me figure the problem?

I used this [article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-tensorflow-image-classification-model-with-your-own-dataset-in-google-colab-63e9d7853a3e) for help.

Comment: your 1997 images validation set is divided into batches of 32 images each, otherwise, you need extreme computation resources to manipulate all the 1997 images at once!

Comment: Can I loop (validation data/batch size) over the validation data because I need a prediction for each of the 1997 images.

Comment: looping over batches is done automatically by the validation generator.

Comment: How do I loop over/access all the batches available? @Bilal